# Use zabbix inside a Dockercontainer to monitor a server

Tags: docker, zabbix, docker-container

I am using Docker container inside my server. I'm running Zabbix service and a Drupal site inside the container.

Is there a way to monitor the server using the Zabbix service I'm running inside the container? How should I configure the zabbix agent so that it monitors the server from inside the container?

I'm new to Docker and Zabbix, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have a look at all the zabbix images availables on the Docker hub https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=zabbix&starCount=0

Comment: @user2915097 I already have zabbix installed in my container. how can i point it to monitor the server?

Comment: check all the info from https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-agent/, and if you need to use zabbix_sender (which uses the port 10051), you will need to modify the configuration

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @user2915097 provided was correct. You just need to have a Zabbix Agent running in another container which will either: a. receive polls from the Zabbix container, or b. send information to the Zabbix container by using the 'active' option.

The server and the agent are typically run as a stack, so all you need to do is download the docker-compose.yml  from the Zabbix page and it does all the necessary linking already.

Answer (score -1):

Docker container is additional layer in your system and it may add also additional level of isolation and security features into your system. Without knowledge about your current Docker/container settings is almost impossible to give you proper solution. Also some host server metrics may not be available directly in the container without additional container configuration. Your question is generic. Be more specific.

Generic answer: please read readme https://github.com/monitoringartist/dockbix-agent-xxl or there is also official doc https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/containers